# Ubuntu 18.04 shows the same icon for all applications at the desktop?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus, icons

1.I have tried creating my own .desktop files for some apps.

2.I have also tried copying the .desktop files directly from usr/share/applications but it shows the same icons for all .desktop files both on the desktop or in a folder other than /usr/share/applications.

3.Have also tried right-clicking the .desktop file and then choosing an icon from /usr/share/icons and then clicking open but no change either in that dialog box or in the icon on the desktop except that the icon= entry reflects the chosen icon. 
As an example this is one of the .desktop files copied directly from usr/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=uGet
GenericName=Download Manager
Comment=Download multiple URLs and apply it to one of setting/queue.
Exec=env GDK_BACKEND=x11 uget-gtk %u
Icon=uget-icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
Keywords=filetransfer;download files;download manager;
```

And this is what it shows [link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGRLz.png) 
[link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dd8L.png)

I get the same result even if I use absolute path to some icon

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=uGet
GenericName=Download Manager
Comment=Download multiple URLs and apply it to one of setting/queue.
Exec=env GDK_BACKEND=x11 uget-gtk %u
Icon=/cab_extract.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
Keywords=filetransfer;download files;download manager;
```

Update 1: I have made it executable using the checkbox and also using the sudo chmod +x command [link3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYWlv.png).It still shows the ugly icon.

Update 2:I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu and it shows custom icons now,so I guess something got broken while I was tweaking around using alacarte.Thanks to vanadium and George for their help.

Comment: So you have an icon at this `/` location as seen in your deaktop file `/cab_extract.png`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen yes,and I used the Select Custom Icon option in the Properties Dialog Box that appears in the right-click context menu of the .desktop file.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add alittle gif to help OP as it appears OP didn't get @vanadium instructions:

[image]

These are the steps to making a `.desktop` file launchable from your dektop. Like the Origianl answer said you have to set the executable permission on that file.

Comment: Thanks for your effort George but I have already tried making it executable, in fact in all the screenshots that I posted,the executable checkbox is checked.

Comment: Oh I see sorry to hear that!

Comment: Is it possible that using the application named 'alacarte'  to manage my Start Menu messed something up and if that is the case how can I undo the changes if it is even possible.BTW I  have clicked on Restore System Configuration option in that application,but it doesn't seems to make any difference.Right now,I will be happy with just resetting it and start over again.